# Rackspace Cloud Databases: incremental backup

Tags: backup, cloud

Rackspace Cloud Databases are a little bit special in that we do not have access to the bin_log file, they are not servers in the traditional sense. I do have a couple of Cloud Servers with them but I want to do incremental backups on my own and am currently looking into ways to do this specifically for Cloud Databases, so far without success.

What options do we have if we want to do incremental backups on Cloud Databases?

**Note:** *I do not want to start a discussion about which method is best, I just want to know which methods are available for this scenario.*

Comment: I am not familiar with this scenario, but still found this http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-to-use-cron-to-backup-cloudsites-to-cloudfiles  and there is a comment ==> there are a few recommendations if needing incremental backups. For Windows and Mac, you could use Expandrive (http://www.expandrive.com/) to mount your filesystem locally. From here you could use the applications backup offerings. For Linux, you could mount your filesystem using SSHFS, then use rsync or dump to make backups.

Comment: Thing is, we dont have access to the filesystem of the database, but thanks anyway